# Logstash ambiguous port definition

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am using Logstash in order to push documents to elasticsearch, and when trying to run logstash I'm getting the error:

[2021-05-09T08:45:57,532][DEBUG][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline terminated by worker error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<LogStash::ConfigurationError: Explicit value for 'port' was declared, but it is different in one of the URLs given! Please make sure your URLs are inline with explicit values. The URLs have the property set to '8001', but it was also set to '443' explicitly>, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-amazon_es-7.0.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/http_client.rb:179:in `calculate_property'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-amazon_es-7.0.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/http_client.rb:228:in` port'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-amazon_es-7.0.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/http_client.rb:66:in `build_url_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-amazon_es-7.0.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/http_client.rb:50:in` initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-amazon_es-7.0.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/http_client_builder.rb:110:in `create_http_client'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-amazon_es-7.0.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/http_client_builder.rb:98:in` build'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-amazon_es-7.0.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es.rb:256:in `build_client'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-amazon_es-7.0.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/common.rb:25:in` register'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/OutputStrategyExt.java:126:in `register'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.java:68:in` register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:226:in `block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1809:in` each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:225:in `register_plugins'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:541:in` maybe_setup_out_plugins'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:238:in `start_workers'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:183:in` run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:134:in `block in start'"], "pipeline.sources"=>["/home/ubuntu/json_try/logstash_try.config"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x1b83bf8e run>"}

I'm trying to figure out where does the port 443 configuration comes from, as I'm also trying http instead of https and specifying port 8001 in the configuration file.
My configuration file for logstash is:

```
input {
        file{
                type => "json"
                path => "~/home/ubuntu/json_try/json_try.json"
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}

output{
        amazon_es {
                hosts => "http://my.dom:8001/scans"
                index => "snapshot-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
        stdout{}
}
```

Is there something to change outside the config file or in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve by explicitly setting the port to be 8001 in the config file, like so:

```
amazon_es {
   hosts => "http://my.dom/scans"
   port => 8001
   index => "snapshot-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
}
```

It solved the duplicate ports problem for me.